# Issue while repacking Lollipop system.img

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, rom, flashing

I want to make some changes in the **system.img** and flash it into my Nexus 5.

To modify the .img I first need to unpack it into filesystem, make the changes anf then repack into new system.img.

I'm following [this guide](http://muzso.hu/2012/08/10/how-to-pack-and-unpack-system.img-and-userdata.img-from-an-android-factory-image) for unpack/repack.

Steps I'm taking:

I. Clone ASOP scripts:

1. `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras`
2. `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux/`
3. `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/`

II. Checkout specific version:

1. `cd extras`
2. `git checkout android-5.1.1_r9`

III. Compiling c files to create make_ext4fs (which is used to repack the filesystem into img)

1. `cd ..`
2. `gcc -o make_ext4fs -Icore/libsparse/include -Ilibselinux/include -Icore/include -lz extras/ext4_utils/canned_fs_config.c extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs.c extras/ext4_utils/ext4fixup.c extras/ext4_utils/ext4_utils.c extras/ext4_utils/allocate.c extras/ext4_utils/contents.c extras/ext4_utils/extent.c extras/ext4_utils/indirect.c extras/ext4_utils/uuid.c extras/ext4_utils/sha1.c extras/ext4_utils/wipe.c core/libsparse/backed_block.c core/libsparse/output_file.c core/libsparse/sparse.c core/libsparse/sparse_crc32.c core/libsparse/sparse_err.c core/libsparse/sparse_read.c`

But above command is giving me error:

```
extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c: In function ‘main’:
extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c:187:20: error: ‘fs_config’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   fs_config_func = fs_config;
                    ^
extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c:187:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

It says fs_config in undeclared. But this is ASOP code, provided by Android only.

What am I missing..?

I think I've included all the header files, but now I'm not sure.

Please help. This is very frustrating.

**P.S.** - I'm a noob in C. So great help if anyone can explain in simple terms.

***Thank You***

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: you're forgetting to include some file(s) in your `gcc` command. Are you sure this doesn't have a `Makefile`?

Comment: @m0skit0 The folder where c file with main() resides is `extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c`. Intrestingly this folder does not have a make file, but all of its sibling folder does have. Now I'm not sure if this is something missed on git or am I missing some step? Also I'm not very fimiler with `make` operation. Please suggest. Will be great help. Thanks!

Comment: Then maybe running `make` in parent folder with also make this executable. Maybe this is not meant to be compiled by itself but rather as part of other tools.

Comment: @m0skit0: I've built `make_ext4fs` successfully by itself.

Comment: @adamblack: Have you tried checking out the same branch (android-5.1.1_r9) for the `core` git as for the `extras` git? IIRC I had trouble building if the gits didn't match.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you please share steps how build it? I'm still stuck.